# Identify if 2 AJAX process is done even if remaining AJAX Processes is still on progress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I know already how to detect if all AJAX Processes is done by the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    alert('All AJAX Process is done.');
});
```

For example there are three AJAX Process: `oneProcess`, `twoProcess`, `threeProcess`.

`oneProcess` and `twoProcess` are already finished and `threeProcess` is still processing. How I invoked that the two AJAX process is done?

Comment: You should probably show the code for those two ajax requests as well

Comment: Do `oneProcess` and `twoProcess` always finish before `threeProcess`?

Comment: You can use `complete ` local event of an ajax to first two process.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to utilize `$.when()`, passing `oneProcess`, `twoProcess` as parameters.

```js
var oneProcess = new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve("oneProcess complete")
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
  return dfd.promise()
}).then(log);

var twoProcess = new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve("twoProcess complete")
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
  return dfd.promise()
}).then(log);

var threeProcess = function(msg) {
  log(msg);
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      dfd.resolve("threeProcess complete")
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    return dfd.promise()
  })
}

function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

var checkOneTwo = $.when(oneProcess, twoProcess);

checkOneTwo.then(function(one, two) {
  threeProcess(
    "oneProcess state:" + oneProcess.state()
    + ", twoProcess state:" + twoProcess.state()
  ).then(log)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Alternatively you can utilize `setInterval` to call `.state()` on each deferred object to check for both `oneProcess`, `twoProcess` `deferred.state()` calls to return `"resolved"`.

```js
var oneProcess = new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve("oneProcess complete")
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
  return dfd.promise()
}).then(log);

var twoProcess = new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve("twoProcess complete")
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
  return dfd.promise()
}).then(log);

var threeProcess = function(msg) {
  log(msg);
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      dfd.resolve("threeProcess complete")
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    return dfd.promise()
  })
}

function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

var interval = null;

var checkOneTwo = function() {
  var oneTwo = new $.Deferred();
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(oneProcess.state() === "resolved"
                , twoProcess.state() === "resolved");
    if (oneProcess.state() === "resolved" &&
        twoProcess.state() === "resolved") {
          clearInterval(interval);
          oneTwo.resolve()
    }
  }, 100);
  return oneTwo.promise().then(function() {
    return threeProcess(
      `oneProcess state:${oneProcess.state()}`
      + `twoProcess state:${twoProcess.state()}`
    )
  })
}

checkOneTwo().then(log);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```